# Slide button with user swipe gesture

Tags: java, android, swipe, ontouchlistener

I want the user to be able to slide a button with their finger either vertically or horizontally (not diagonally) the length of the button.

Example:  Button is 50dp long and wide.  The user will swipe to the right and the button will move 50dp to the right.

Right now I have the below code which prompts a Toast correctly depending on which way the user swipes.

GameScreen

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {

    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamescreen);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setText("BUTTON");
        btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

OnSwipeTouchListener

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    Context context;

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

My question is how can I get the button to actually move instead of just prompting a Toast?

Comment: Try translating the button. btnView.animate().translate().......

Comment: Take the current position on touch and set in btn1.setTranslationX() and setTranslationY()

Comment: @Rani - Thanks!  `btn1.setTranslationX/Y()` worked like I wanted it to.

Comment: Glad it helped you! I will add as answer and Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the current position on touch and set in btn1.setTranslationX() and setTranslationY().